# PrimeNG TabView does not use theme colors

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am using the md-dark-deeppurple theme of PrimeNG.
I have installed primeng, primeicons and primeflex.
I also added all necessary imports in the angular.json:

[image: angular.json]

Unforunately the theme seems not to be used on the p-tabView component for some reason.

[image: example]

As you can see on the picture the p-dataView component does have the dark colors of the theme but the p-tabView does not. I think I also imported all the necessary modules:

[image: module imports]

And when you check on the PrimeNG page and set the theme in question you will see that the TabView should have the dark colors.

[image: primeng example page]

The HTML is pretty straight forward:
`<p-tabMenu [model]="menuItems"></p-tabMenu>`

I am also not overriding any css.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the app?

Comment: Yes multiple times. I also cleared browser cache and even restared my IDE.

Comment: Just in case, I also constantly stumble on this, in the angular.json file, did you put the styles in the "styles" array related to the "build" or "test"?

Comment: It is in build.

Comment: So I looked around the PrimeNG page using the chrome dev tools. The TabView seems to have a transparent background and since my body is white it obviously is white. And to me it seems like on the PrimeNG site they set a background-color for the whole body according to the selected theme. I am not sure if this is intended? Should I just do the same then and apply a background-color to my whole body?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know :( Try to experimenting with other themes, may be it will help

Comment: @Onetwo yeah I will continue to look around. Thank you for your time!